# select specific columns from complex lines

Tags: perl, awk

I have a file that contains lines with the following format. I would like to keep only the **first column** and the column containing the string with the following format **NC_XXXX.1**

```
484-2117    16  gi|9634679|ref|NC_002188.1| 188705  23  21M *   0   0   CGCGTACCAAAAGTAATAATT   IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII   AS:i:-6 XN:i:0  XM:i:1  XO:i:0  XG:i:0  NM:i:1  MD:Z:0G20   YT:Z:UU
787-1087    16  gi|21844535|ref|NC_004068.1|    7006    23  20M *   0   0   CTATACAACCTACTACCTCA    IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII    AS:i:-6 XN:i:0  XM:i:1  XO:i:0  XG:i:0  NM:i:1  MD:Z:19T0   YT:Z:UU
.....
....
...
```

output:

```
484-2117 NC_002188.1
787-1087 NC_004068.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this in perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
   my ( $id, $nc ) = m/^([\d\-]+).*(NC_[\d\.]+)/;
   print "$id $nc\n";
}

__DATA__
484-2117    16  gi|9634679|ref|NC_002188.1| 188705  23  21M *   0   0   CGCGTACCAAAAGTAATAATT   IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII   AS:i:-6 XN:i:0  XM:i:1  XO:i:0  XG:i:0  NM:i:1  MD:Z:0G20   YT:Z:UU
787-1087    16  gi|21844535|ref|NC_004068.1|    7006    23  20M *   0   0   CTATACAACCTACTACCTCA    IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII    AS:i:-6 XN:i:0  XM:i:1  XO:i:0  XG:i:0  NM:i:1  MD:Z:19T0   YT:Z:UU
```

Output:

```
484-2117 NC_002188.1
787-1087 NC_004068.1
```

Which reduces to a one liner of:

```
perl -ne 'm/^([\d\-]+).*(NC_[\d\.]+)/ and print "$1 $2\n"'   yourfile
```

Note - this specifically matches a first column made up of number and dash - you could do this with a wider regex match.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F' +|\\|' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ /^NC_[0-9.]+$/) {print $1,$i; next}}' file
484-2117 NC_002188.1
787-1087 NC_004068.1
```

if the space is a tab char, need to add to the delimiter list

```
$ awk -F' +|\\||\t' ...
```

Comment: That almost worked, but it outputs 16  gi as well on my data

Comment: The space is perhaps a tab, need to add to field delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu-awk below could be solution:

```
awk '{printf "%s %s\n",$1,gensub(/.*(NC_.*\.1).*/,"\\1",1,$0)}' file
```

**Output**

```
484-2117 NC_002188.1
787-1087 NC_004068.1
```

A more restrictive version would be

```
awk '{printf "%s %s\n",$1,gensub(/.*(NC_[[:digit:]]*\.1).*/,"\\1",1,$0)}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With perl:

```
perl -anE'say "$F[0] ",(split /\|/, $F[2])[3]' file
```

or awk:

```
awk -F'\\|| +' '{print $1,$6}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[ |]' '{print $1,$10}' file
484-2117 NC_002188.1
787-1087 NC_004068.1
```